# Import MSAccess DB into Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, ms-access, import, azure-sql-database

I have several accdb files that I would like to import into one single Azure DB.

Currently I am using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Since this manual task is very error prone I would like to know if there is a possibility to automate it.

Comment: Have you tried googling "Import MSAccess DB into Azure SQL DB"?

Comment: To ask google was the first thing I did, but didn't find an answer. I don't want to import just once but automate it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use the free and official (and excellent) tool for this, currently at version 8:

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 8.0 for Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255)

> Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Access is a tool
>   to automate migration from Microsoft Access database(s) to SQL Server,
>   Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Database Managed Instance.

Comment: I used SSMA but as far as I know it cannot be automated, right?

Comment: Can't tell, but read on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @TheWizard I am still trying to find a solution. Did you find one? I Cant believe how Microsoft poorly design is own system

Comment: @Simon GIS Unfortunatly not. I wrote a script to transfer the data.